# $(document).ready() is not working after coming back from another page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am developing an application in asp.net using c#. In my page I have done ajax call to load the page with html. The html code is coming from the database. This ajax call is written in the document.ready() function. When I am first time loading the page its working fine. When I am going to another page, that is also working fine. But when I am trying to coming back from that page then the document.ready() is not working. For that reason the html code is also not getting populated. How can I solve this issue please help me out from here.

Document.ready() code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    tempName = GetParameterValues("templateName");
    //alert(tempName);
    if (tempName != "" || tempName != null) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "DesignCenter_Static.aspx/loadTemplatePackage",
            data: "{'template_name':'" + tempName.toString() + "'}",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) {
                var temp_data = data.d.toString();
                var temp_arr = new Array();
                temp_arr = temp_data.split("|");

                $("#divTemplateLayout").html(temp_arr[0].toString());
                $("#inputForm").html(temp_arr[1].toString());
                $("#divButtonSet").html(temp_arr[2].toString());


                $("#inputForm").find('[id^="txt"]').each(function () {
                    var cName, labelControlName, divControlName, resizeClassName, existingClassName, txtName;
                    txtName = $(this).attr("id");
                    cName = txtName.slice(3, txtName.length);
                    divControlName = "lbl" + cName;

                    $("#" + divControlName + "").resizable({
                        maxWidth: 300,
                        minHeight: 16,
                        minWidth: 50,
                        containment: "parent",
                        autoHide: true,
                        handles: "n, e, s, w, ne, se, sw, nw"
                    });
                    $("#" + divControlName + "").draggable({ cursor: 'move', containment: ".setLimit" });
                });

            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }

    $("#ddlZoom").val("100%");
    currentZoomLevel = $("#ddlZoom").val();
    fillInitialDesignStudio();
});
```

Back Button Code of another page is as follows:

```
$(function () {
        $("#btnBack").click(function () {
            var resPage = GetParameterValues("responsePage");
            var tempName = GetParameterValues("templateName");
            window.location.href = resPage + "?returnPage=BC_Proof.aspx&templateName=" + tempName;
        });
    });
```

Master page code for adding jquery library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/holder.js"></script>
<%--<script src="js/colpick.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/placeholders.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.uploadify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.uploadify.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/spectrum.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scolor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>

<script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.button.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.menu.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.tooltip.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is your jquery library included in your HTML? Please, add that section to your example too.

Comment: All the Jquery library added in the master page.

Comment: I have added JQUERY library reference code please check the post.

Answer (score 0):

issue is `templateName` not getting properly , Check Ajax data,

```
   data: "{'template_name':'" + tempName.toString() + "'}",
```

Your BackButton Code:

```
   var tempName = GetParameterValues("templateName");
```

use `GetParameterValues("template_name");` instead of `GetParameterValues("templateName");`

Comment: I have added a alert before fetching the templateName, that alert is also not showing.